# MySql count () to return 0 if no records found

Tags: mysql

I try to do a COUNT in a table where possibly there is no record to count, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN, none of them work, what happens?

If there are no records, is it possible for COUNT to say zero?

```
CREATE TABLE clase (
  cla_id INTEGER,
  cla_name varchar(5) NOT NULL
) 


CREATE TABLE products (
 product_type int,
 product varchar(10),
 cla_name varchar(5)
) 

insert into clase (cla_id,cla_name ) values
(1,'A'),
(2,'B'),
(3,'C'),
(4,'D')


insert into products (product_type,product,cla_name ) values
(29,'P0001','A'),
(29,'P0002','A'),
(29,'P0003','A'),
(29,'P0004','A'),
(29,'P0005','A'),
(29,'P0006','A'),
(29,'P0007','B'),
(29,'P0008','B'),
(29,'P0009','B'),
(29,'P0010','C'),
(29,'P0011','C'),
(29,'P0012','C'),
(29,'P0013','B'),
(29,'P0014','B')
```

this is the simple query I am using

```
SELECT c.cla_name, COUNT(p.cla_name)
FROM clase c
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.cla_name = c.cla_name
WHERE p.product_type = 29
GROUP BY c.cla_name




The result:
cla_name    COUNT(p.cla_name)
A                6
B                5
C                3
```

The result expected:

```
cla_name    COUNT(p.cla_name)
A                6
B                5
C                3
D                0
```

[See the Fiddle Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=9ff6619ebfce455fb624853e4c715451)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the criteria in the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the join:

```
SELECT c.cla_name, COUNT(p.cla_name)
FROM clase c
LEFT JOIN products p
    ON p.cla_name = c.cla_name AND
       p.product_type = 29
GROUP BY c.cla_name;
```

Because the `WHERE` filter is happening before the join, your current query removes the `D` name record from the `clase` table before the join happens.